# Change image name and save to DB Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload

Hi i can not store image name to database in Laravel project.
How to solve this?

Here is codes of controller

```
 class TarifController extends Controller
{
  public function store(Request $request)
   {
    $request->validate([
        'title_uz' => 'required',
        'desc_uz' => 'required',
        'full_desc_uz' => 'required',
        'company_id' => 'required',
        'order' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
    $image1 = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $image1);
    Tarif::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('tarifs.index')
        ->with('success','Yangi tarif muvoffaqiyatli qo`shildi.');
  }
}
```

and here is codes from view

```
<form role="form" action="{{ route('tarifs.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
 <div> .. another fields ..  </div>
 <div class="col-5">
     <label for="image">Surat</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image" required>
 </div>
<div> .. another fields ..  </div>
<div class="card-footer">
     <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('tarifs.index') }}">Qaytish</a>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Saqlash</button>
</div>
</form>
```

It saves image to public/images folder but didn't saves filename or path to DB. The field name is 'image' on database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to merge new values into a request object, the following code would have done the trick :

```
$request->merge(['image' => 'avatar.png']);
```

Or, you can change your code like this :

```
$image1 = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
$request->image->move(public_path('images'), $image1);
$input = $request->all();
$input['image'] = $image1;
Tarif::create($input);
```

Comment: I made changes like yours but it saves data like this "W:\userdata\temp\php69E2.tmp".
But when I capture request it returns [ "image" => "1604906402.jpeg"].